# If the mean of four non-negative integers $ a < b < c < d $ is $ 100 $, find the minimum value of $ a + d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If the mean of four non-negative integers $ a < b < c < d $ is $ 100 $, what is the minimum value of $ a + d $?
It seems a easy problem..But I don't know how to solve it. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First approach:

**Hint:** $b \leq d-2$, $c \leq d-1$.

**Hint:** $ 400 = a + b + c + d $.

---

Second approach:

Let $(a^*, b^*, c^*, d^*)$ be the solution set which minimizes $a+d$. Then we see that

$(0, b^*, c^*, a^* + d^*)$ is also such a set.

What conditions can you set now?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I think I got it:Given the first hint, $b+c \leq 2d-3$. Using the second hint, $a+3d \geq 403$. The second approach says $a$ could be zero. So $d \geq \frac{403}{3}$. Hence the minimum of $a+d$ is $135$. Did I follow you right?

Comment: @user1500178 Yup. For completeness, in order to show that is indeed the minimum, you have to find a set which satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Here is one: $(0,131,134,135)$. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Calvin Lin's second approach:

> Let $(a^∗,b^∗,c^∗,d^∗)$ be the solution set which minimizes $a+da+d$. Then we see that
>   $(0,b^∗,c^∗,a^∗+d^∗)$ is also such a set.

Let's denote $a^∗+d^∗$ as $d'$.

$b^*+c^*+d'=400$, in order to minimize, $b^*+c^*$ should be as large as possible, in extreme context $b^*$ should approaches $c^*$ and $c^*$ approaches $d'$, so it is $\frac{400}3\approx 133$, consider numbers around $133$, you will find $135$ is the required answer.